# How to infer return type from parameter type in a generic function?

Tags: typescript, conditional-types, typescript2.8

Here is some code with conditional type

```
class A {
    public a: number;
}

class B {
    public b: number;
}

type DataType = "a" | "b";

type TData<T extends DataType> =
    T extends "a" ? A :
    T extends "b" ? B :
    never;
```

Now I want to use conditional type as a link from function parameter to its return type. I tried to achieve this in different ways with no result:

```
function GetData<T extends DataType>(dataType: T): TData<T> {
    if (dataType == "a")
        return new A();
    else if (dataType == "b")
        return new B();
}
```

What is the proper syntax? Is it possible with TypeScript 2.8?

**Update**

There is already an [opened issue on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24085) that covers my example.
So current answer is "No, but may be possible in future".

Answer (score 4):

You can use function overloads here:

```
function GetData(dataType: "a"): A;
function GetData(dataType: "b"): B;
function GetData(dataType: DataType): A | B {
    if (dataType === "a")
        return new A();
    else if (dataType === "b")
        return new B();
}

const f = GetData('a');  // Inferred A
const g = GetData('b');  // Inferred B
```

Comment: This will become cumbersome when in real code `DataType` transforms  into a large enum.

Answer (score 0):

The ternary operator really doesn't play nice with generic types:

```
type TriviallyA<T extends DataType> = 
      T extends any ? A : A;
function GetData<T extends 'a' = 'a'>(dataType: T): TriviallyA<T> {
    return new A(); // Error: Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'TriviallyA<T>'
}
```

However generics do play nice with attribute lookup, so you can define an interface to map strings to particular types, then you can use `keyof` and attribute lookup to act as `TData`:

```
interface DataTypeMapping {
    a: A;
    b: B;
}
type DataType = keyof DataTypeMapping;
type TData<T extends DataType> = DataTypeMapping[T];

function GetData<T extends DataType>(dataType: T): TData<T> {
    // now expected return type is A | B so this is valid!
    if (dataType === 'a') {
        return new A(); 
    } else if (dataType === 'b') {
        return new B();
    }
}
```